# Atmospheric correction for Airbus imagery

Tags: python, open-source-gis, atmospheric-correction, flaash

I have purchased images from Airbus using sentinel hub and realized that [they are TOA (top of atmosphere)](https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/data/airbus/pleiades/). I would like to apply atmospheric correction on the images.

I have seen the FLAASH is very popular, however, seems like I need ENVI for using it.

I wanted to ask if there are any open sources options for doing atmospheric correction for the AIRBUS imagery.

I wonder if someone here had the same issue and what are the solutions you have found for atmospheric correction of Airbus imagery using open-source software.

Comment: Do you want to apply a relative or absolute atmospheric correction?

Comment: @aldo_tapia I prefer absolute but also relative is good (better than nothing...)

Answer (score -1):

I think, you don't need to make additional atmospheric correction because you have high quality, TOA is a kind of atmospheric correction. Just have to scale the values of pixels from `int` to `float`.